# graph algorithm question

Tags: algorithm

How can I find all available path for each Vertices which won't cause a cycle? What algorithm to use? Please be brief and provide links if possible, and ask questions if something is not clear from the wonderful diagram below :)
[image: asdas]

I am not looking for a shortest path or anything like that. Instead I just want to know which paths I can still draw on my graph without causing a loop/cycle. For example `L4` can goto `L1, L2, L5` AND `L2` can goto `L5`...and so on....

I guess I want a Directed acyclic graph and need help finding out which algorithm to use and how?

Comment: In your example, how can L4 goto L5?

Comment: No it is not homework. Just haven't used any of the algorithm for a while and have a need to use one now. So I thought what better place to learn than the wonderful SO :)

Comment: @Amit S: You would draw a line from `L4` to `L5` with the arrow pointing at `L5` :)

Comment: @VoodooChild: My bad. I didn't read your question properly.

Comment: @Amit S: No big deal, I thought maybe I might have made an error in my question.

Comment: Yes, you are trying to preserve a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: I don't understand the grammar in your first sentence. Please check it again. Is your goal to construct a list of all those paths in the graph, that do not contain a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the Ford Algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

Enjoy',

Answer (score 2):

A shortest-path algorithm like Bellman-Ford or Dijkstra has the side effect of telling you which nodes you can reach from a given node "A" -- which is exactly the list of nodes from which edges **to** "A" would form a loop.

I suspect there is a way to modify Bellman-Ford to generate all these lists in one go, instead of running the algorithm separately for every node, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Following is not the answer but just a way to think for this problem. 
You can think for the problem from the opposite side. Find all the paths that have exactly one edge missing to form a cycle(I havn't think of it, how). Then those missing edges are not the edges you are looking. Accept everything other than that.